# SQLite + Webservice (json) - MySql

Tags: android, webservice, sqlite

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de seguimiento con la clase `LocationManager` accediendo a las latitudes y longitudes del *gps* y se suben al servidor con `jsonparser` cada minuto por medio de un `Handler`.

Quiero hacer una base de datos local con `SQlite` para cuando no exista conexión a internet. Mi pregunta es con qué herramienta sincronizar (Service , Asyntask , radiodifusion) con el servidor web y como hacer para que la base de datos local no quede tan pesada (borrar registros ya subidos).

Uso AndroidStudio, **api 23**.

Adjunto mi `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView mensaje1;
    TextView mensaje2;
    TextView hora;
    String id;
    TextView uno;

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String REGISTER_URL = "http://www.syan.cl/musicminguzzi.cl/gps/gps.php";
    String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mensaje1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mensaje_id);
        mensaje2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mensaje_id2);
        uno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ide);
        hora = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hour);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras !=null)
        {
            id = (String) extras.get("user");
            uno.setText(id);
        }


        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CreateUser().execute();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 60000); //now is every 2 minutes
            }
        }, 60000); //Every 120000 ms (2 minutes)






        /* Uso de la clase LocationManager para obtener la localizacion del GPS */
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Localizacion Local = new Localizacion();
        Local.setMainActivity(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                (LocationListener) Local);

        mensaje1.setText("Localizacion agregada");
        mensaje2.setText("");
    }



    public void setLocation(Location loc) {
        //Obtener la direccion de la calle a partir de la latitud y la longitud

    }

    /* Aqui empieza la Clase Localizacion */
    public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
        MainActivity mainActivity;

        public MainActivity getMainActivity() {
            return mainActivity;
        }

        public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity) {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cada vez que el GPS recibe nuevas coordenadas
            // debido a la deteccion de un cambio de ubicacion


            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            Double Text =  loc.getLatitude();
            Double Text1 =  loc.getLongitude();
            mensaje2.setText(Text1.toString());
            mensaje1.setText(Text.toString());
            this.mainActivity.setLocation(loc);
            long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
            String dateString = sdf.format(date);
            hora.setText(dateString);



        }



        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es desactivado
            mensaje1.setText("GPS Desactivado");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es activado
            mensaje1.setText("GPS Activado");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cada vez que se detecta un cambio en el
            // status del proveedor de localizacion (GPS)
            // Los diferentes Status son:
            // OUT_OF_SERVICE -> Si el proveedor esta fuera de servicio
            // TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE -> Temporalmente no disponible pero se
            // espera que este disponible en breve
            // AVAILABLE -> Disponible
            // admin data base result
        }

    }


    class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dateString = sdf.format(date);


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Subiendo Coordenadas...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = mensaje2.getText().toString();
            String password = mensaje1.getText().toString();
            String ide = uno.getText().toString();
            String hora = dateString;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List params = new ArrayList();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ide", ide));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hora", hora));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        REGISTER_URL, "POST", params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Registering attempt", json.toString());

                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Registering Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido! Tu pregunta es demasiada amplia, puedo adivinar que tu app es en Android, pero no lo mencionas. Si editas tu pregunta, la divides por partes   y además muestras el código que llevas actualmente es muy probable que alguien te ayude :)

Comment: A falta de código siempre viene bien literatura. Estoy con @x4mp73r , si no pones código o explicas mejor lo que llevas hecho sólo podemos ayudarte con literatura y enlaces a fuentes que puedan ayudarte.

Comment: ahora sip, sorry soy nuevo en esto

Comment: ¿Solucionaste tu problema? ¿Alguna respuesta te ayudó? ¿Necesitas un ejemplo del [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) que te propuse?

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado necesitas borrar los registros subidos con un simple [`DELETE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html). Cada vez que conectes al servidor deberás enviar todos los registros que tengas almacenados en la base de datos SQLite y borrarlos cuando confirmes su recepción.

Tras un tiempo de funcionamiento probablemente el tamaño de la base de datos aumente debido a los "huecos" que dejan los registros borrados. Para compactar el tamaño de la base de datos necesitarás hacer un [`VACUUM`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html). Te recomiendo hacer el `VACUUM` cuando el usuario cierre la aplicación, o bien al abrirla.

Es fácil implementar las actualizaciones con [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Pero quizá debas implementar alguna forma de detectar un envío anterior a medias, o no enviar el siguiente dato si no se ha terminado el envío anterior y, en su lugar, añadirlo a la base de datos para que se envíe durante la siguiente actualización.